# How to append outer div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add a div outside of this..Like

```
<addDiv>

  <div>
  ---------
   Code 
  ---------
  </div>

</endDiv>
```

any suggestion ??

Comment: use `.wrapAll()` or `.wrap()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("div").wrapAll('<div class=wrapper></div>')

$("span").wrap('<div class=wrapper></div>')
```

```css
.wrapper {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
</div>

<div>
  11
</div>

<div>
  111
</div>

<span>1</span>

<span>1</span>
```

1. Use `.wrap()` if you only want to wrap only one div
2. Use `.wrapAll()` for multiple div to wrap in one wrapper

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="tempdiv">Hello</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var html = "<div id='outerDiv' style="height:100px;width:100px;background-
  color:red;"></div>";
 $(body).append(html);
 var x = $("#tempDiv");
$("#tempDiv").remove();
$("#outerDiv").append(x);
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery **wrap**.

Basically you would do something like:

```
$( ".inside-div-class" ).wrap('<div class="outside-div"></div>');
```

> Source : https://api.jquery.com/wrap/